# What is inscribed around the muzzle of Deadpool's gun?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2

In the James Bond-style opening credits of Deadpool 2, there's a moment where Deadpool points a pistol directly at the camera. There's something written there in engraved letters around the muzzle of the gun. I'm pretty sure it said "SMILE" along the upper edge, but I couldn't make out the rest of it - there seemed to be a few words at the bottom edge.

What does it say, and is this just a one-off joke, or a canonical thing that's always written on Wade's guns?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The muzzle says,

> "SMILE
>   WAIT FOR THE FLASH".

A quick google search tells me that that particular phrase is a popular engraving for muzzles. There doesn't seem to be anything that relates it to Deadpool though.

[image]

Comment: Wow, there really are a lot of these online (in addition to other, occasionally quite offensive variants...). Too bad they couldn't come up with a more uniquely Deadpool-ish joke.

Comment: Probably was a last minute add on. "Hey VFX, could you think of something cool to put on the muzzle? ... What's that? Yeah cool. Anything's fine. Get it done."

Comment: It's a fun (meta) joke about getting shot in a picture.